# Export large dataset (JSON) from PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgis, large-data

I have a postgres database with geospatial data and I want to export certain parts of those as a GeoJSON.

So I have a SQL-Command like the following:

```
SELECT jsonb_build_object ( 'some_test_data', jsonb_agg (ST_AsGeoJSON (ST_Transform (way, 4326))::jsonb)) as json
FROM (
  SELECT way, name, highway
  FROM planet_osm_line
  LIMIT 10) result
```

and that basically works fine. I can also save it to a file and dump it directly to a file like so:

```
psql -qtAX -d my-database -f my_cool_sql_command.sql > result.json
```

So my data is correct and usable, but now I'd like to remove the `LIMIT 10` and I get `ERROR:  total size of jsonb array elements exceeds the maximum of 268435455 bytes`

I've read that it's not easy to remove this 256MB limit of postgres... But I guess there are other ways to get my result?

Comment: consider flagging and asking to move to [dba.se]

Comment: It should be 1GB at least from version 9.3 (i've checkd again and it is for json not jsonb). Also you can try to connect to your DB with some GIS tool as QGIS, ArcGis, MapInfo and open your table first in that tools (will be extremly hard most of this tools have problems with files bigger then few millions of rows) and save as geojson from it.

Comment: Other way is to import such file in few parts. Just create function and split result every 100 000 rows or something

Comment: And next approche - if way is a linestring first use st_simplify() on it . It will make file much smaller.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I guess splitting up the result in like 100 000 rows per request sounds good to me!
UI Tools are not an options as it's going to run on a linux with shell only
And I am locally using postgres 10 and it seems to still have the 256 mb limit?!?

Answer (score 0):

Try approach with shrinking the file be simplifying the geometry with st_simplify() and json_build_object() (should be 1 GB limit [same as a limit for text] not 256 MB as for binary files)

```
SELECT json_build_object('some_test_data', json_agg (ST_AsGeoJSON (ST_Transform (way, 4326))::json)) as json
  FROM (SELECT st_simplify(way,1) way, name, highway
          FROM planet_osm_line) result
```

You can simplify more then for 1 meter but with 1 meter you usually don't lose any important vertices on your graph.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I currently have the problem with only a quite small dataset already. If I'd try to export the whole world, I'd have to simplify far too much. Aren't there any other workarounds for the problem? But thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Nothing more then i wrote before in comments to your question. But can you explain me what is the purpose of exporting such large file as geojson, maybe there is another way for your functionality?

Comment: I need my data as GeoJSON to create vector tiles using tippecannoe... If you'd have any other suggestions, I'd be super happy :)